# List to Datatable and add column

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, datatable

I have generic list ... I am trying to convert it to a data table.

I am using below code..

```
private DataTable ToDataTable<T>(List<T> items)
{
        var tb = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);

        PropertyInfo[] props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
        {
            Type t = GetCoreType(prop.PropertyType);
            tb.Columns.Add(prop.Name, t);
        }

        foreach (T item in items)
        {
            var values = new object[props.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < props.Length; i++)
            {
             values[i] = props[i].GetValue(item, null);

            }

            tb.Rows.Add(values);
        }

        return tb;
}
```

I need to add another column in that datatable, say `StatusText`.

There is already a column in that datatable called `Status`.

If this column is 0 then `StatusText` should be `Active`, or if it is 1 then `StatusText` will be `Inactive`

Like my code returns below table currently...

```
Id   Name  Status
------------------
1    Test   1
2    Test1  0
3    Test2  0
```

But, how can I generate table like below?

```
Id   Name  Status  StatusText
------------------------------
1    Test   1       InActive
2    Test1  0       Active
3    Test2  0       Active
```

Comment: Surely not every type T you pass to the function will have the extra column? Why not simply add the property to those types that need it, and it will be picked up like the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
DataTable dt = ToDataTable(your list); // Get DataTable From List

dt.Columns.Add(new Column("StatusText", typeof(string))); // Add New Column StatusText


//Iterate All Rows 
foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
   //Check Status value, and set StatusText accordingly. 
   row["StatusText"] = int.Parse(row["Status"])==1 ? "InActive" : "Active";
}
```

Comment: This way the function will become of no use to for generating datatables for other classes who don't need the statustext.

Comment: @AmazingDreams yes, its true, but some times, we have no control on coming data. In such a case, this will help, otherwise, it is better to add additional property in the class.

Comment: This was an excellent dynamic function with which you could put every class inside a datatable. Simply adding a property to the classes who need it would keep it that way. I think your answer adds a lot of unneccesary code, ignoring the whole lot of things you can do with properties.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this in your class defenition:

```
   public string StatusText
   {
    get
    {
       if(status == 0)
          return "Active";
       else
          return "InActive";
     }
   }
```